# tmux - Automate start of tmux server, in order to run tmux .config scripts

Tags: tmux

I am calling a ".tmux-conf" file and get the error:

```
no server running on /tmp/tmux-1000/default
```

If I manually start a tmux session, prior to call above file, everything works fine, since the tmux session opens the tmux server.

This is part of an automation so I need to embedd the start of the tmux server. 
Any suggestions of what is the most minimal, straightforward way of securing start of the tmux server, without manually starting it?

Answer (score 0):

Before the call `tmux source-file .tmux.conf` you need to actually have a session running in tmux. You should run `tmux new-session -s sessionname -f .tmux.conf` where the option `-f` lets you specify the conf file you want to use, in this case `.tmux.conf`. As an alternative, you create the session with `tmux new-session -s sessionname -d`, you call the conf file with `tmux source-file .tmux.conf`, and finally attach to the session with `tmux attach`.

For reference, this is extracted from the `man tmux`:

> -f file Specify an alternative configuration file.  By default, tmux loads the system configuration file from /etc/tmux.conf, if present,
> then looks for a user configuration file at ~/.tmux.conf,
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/tmux/tmux.conf or ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf. The
> configuration file is a set of tmux commands which are executed in
> sequence when the server is first started. **tmux loads configuration
> files once when the server process has started**. The source-file
> command may be used to load a file later. tmux shows any error
> messages from commands in configuration files in the first session
> created, and continues to process the rest of the configuration file.